# having problem with flutter dialog box, after catching an error its showing me a black page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a **Dialog Widgets**, It will show the Dialog+progeress indicator when a user login and signup. As usual dialogue box. Its works perfectly when there is no error like authencated user and password if you provide it will show the Dialog perfectly.
but when I put the wrong email id or password or make any mistake its show me a black blank page where I need to restart the app again. I want that if I am in **signup** mode if the error occurred it will show me the error message and keep me on the login page, the same thing for the registration page. I user  `Navigator.pop(context)`  to stop the dialogue but its stops the dialogue and show me a black blank page. But when it finds an error like I put a wrong email it takes me to the black page, I want that if it's found any error after showing the message it will keep me on my login page, so I can put a valid email and password.

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:ride_share_app/AllScreen/mainscreen.dart';
import 'package:ride_share_app/AllScreen/registrationScreen.dart';
import 'package:ride_share_app/AllWidgets/progressDailog.dart';
import 'package:ride_share_app/main.dart';

class LogInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String idScreen = 'loginScreen';

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void  loginAutentcatUser(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      showDialog(context: context, 
      builder: (BuildContext contex){
        return ProgressDialog(message: 'Authenticating Please wait',);
      });
      final firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
              .catchError((errMsg) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
        displayToastMessage('Error Msg 01: ' + errMsg.toString(), context);
      }))
          .user;
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).once().then(
               (DataSnapshot snap) {
                if (snap.value != null) {
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
                  displayToastMessage('You are Loggied in', context);
                }
                else {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  
                  _firebaseAuth.signOut();

                  displayToastMessage(
                      'User does not found, Create new account', context);
                      
                }
              },

            );
      } else{
        Navigator.pop(context);
        displayToastMessage('Error occured', context);
      }
    }   on PlatformException catch (err) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      displayToastMessage('Error: 02 '+ err.toString(), context);
    }catch (err) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
       displayToastMessage('Error: 03 ' + err.toString(), context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                  height: 350,
                  width: 250,
                  image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Login As Rider',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Brand Bold', fontSize: 24),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 08,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.email,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      labelText: 'Email',
                      labelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 08,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: passwordController,
                  obscureText: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.password,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      labelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 08,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                        if (emailController.text.isEmpty ||
                          !emailController.text.contains(RegExp(
                              '^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]+.[com]'))) {
                        displayToastMessage('Email is not valid', context);
                      }
                      else if (passwordController.text.isEmpty ||
                          passwordController.text.length < 8) {
                        displayToastMessage(
                            'password must be 9 cherectars', context);
                      }
                      else{
                            loginAutentcatUser(context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Login')),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
                          RegistrationScrren.idScreen, (route) => false);
                    },
                    child: Text('Create New Account..'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my whole code for user login.

```dart
 void  loginAutentcatUser(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      showDialog(context: context, 
      builder: (BuildContext contex){
        return ProgressDialog(message: 'Authenticating Please wait',);
      });
      final firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
              .catchError((errMsg) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
        displayToastMessage('Error Msg 01: ' + errMsg.toString(), context);
      }))
          .user;
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).once().then(
               (DataSnapshot snap) {
                if (snap.value != null) {
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
                  displayToastMessage('You are Loggied in', context);
                }
                else {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  
                  _firebaseAuth.signOut();

                  displayToastMessage(
                      'User does not found, Create new account', context);
                      
                }
              },

            );
      } else{
        Navigator.pop(context);
        displayToastMessage('Error occured', context);
      }
    }   on PlatformException catch (err) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      displayToastMessage('Error: 02 '+ err.toString(), context);
    }catch (err) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
       displayToastMessage('Error: 03 ' + err.toString(), context);
    }
  }
```

this code shows that if any error occurs or catch it will use `Navigator.pop(context)`  to stop the dialogue.
[image: This picture shows the dialog and progress indicator]

[image: But when it find error like i put a wrong email it takes me to the black page, I want that if its found any error after showing the message it will keep me on my login page]

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies here :

```
 void  loginAutentcatUser(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      showDialog(context: context, 
      builder: (BuildContext contex){
.....
.....
    }catch (err) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
       displayToastMessage('Error: 03 ' + err.toString(), context);
    }
```

Note that the context that you are passing to the navigator when calling `pop` is the context of the `LogInScreen` widget, which is apparently the only route in the navigator and why you are left with a black screen. You shold be calling

```
Navigator.pop(contex);
```

With `contex`, minus the `t` that is how you named the dialog context, or even better be more explicit about it and rename `contex` to something more sensible like `dialogContext` :

```
 void  loginAutentcatUser(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      showDialog(context: context, 
      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext){
.....
.....
    }catch (err) {
      Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
       displayToastMessage('Error: 03 ' + err.toString(), context);
    }
```

now its clear in your code that you are popping the dialog and no the entire route.

Comment: but sir,when i am changing my ** builder: (BuildContext dialogContext)** its showing some error likes **add a local variable, add a field,  ** I am really confused @croxx5f

Comment: ``` void  loginAutentcatUser(BuildContext context) async {
  var dialogContext;
    try {
      showDialog(context: context, 
      builder: (BuildContext _dialogContext){
  dialogContext=_dialogContext;
  ```